# exporting query result to multitab excel workbook

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to export 4 query result set to a single multi-tab workbook in excel.  My environment is 64-bit sql server 2008. None of the examples I have seen work.

Comment: use Aspose Dlls.though you have to pay for them,they make working with excel just like table

Comment: Please show examples of what you have tried? I have used `OpenDataSource` queries inserting into the excel tab. Only drawback is the tab has to exist. So I use excel templates and copy the template to the finished file.

Comment: Can you use SSRS?